# How to convert cell formula to script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I change this simple cell formula to a script that will be apply to the sheet :

```
=if(D3="Devis";B3+8;(if(D3<>"Devis";"")))
```

Where :

- **C column** contains the formula
- **"Devis"** is a name presents in the **D column**
- **B column** contains Dates

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First you need something that will trigger the script.  So you'll need something like a simple `onEdit()` function, or a change trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var valueOfCellEdited = e.value;
  Logger.log('valueOfCellEdited: ' + valueOfCellEdited);

  var columnOfCellEdited = e.range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('columnOfCellEdited: ' + columnOfCellEdited);

  var rowOfCellEdited = e.range.getRow();
  Logger.log('rowOfCellEdited: ' + rowOfCellEdited);

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 3) {
    var valueToGet = sh.getRange(rowOfCellEdited, 4);
    var dateToGet = "";

    if (valueOfCellEdited === "Devis") { //Date to write is already set to an empty string, so no "Else" needed
      var dateInColB = sh.getRange(rowOfCellEdited, 2).getValue();
      Logger.log('dateInColB: ' + dateInColB);
      Logger.log('typeof dateInColB: ' + typeof dateInColB);

      dateToGet = new Date(dateInColB);
      var dateInMilliseconds = dateToGet.valueOf();
      Logger.log('dateInMilliseconds: ' + dateInMilliseconds);
      //60 seconds in a minute = 60 * 1000 = 60000 milliseconds in a minute. 
      //60 minutes in a hour = 60,000 * 60 = 3,600,000
      //24 hours in day 3,600,000 * 24 = 86,400,000
      var datePlusEight = dateInMilliseconds + (8 * 86400000);
      Logger.log('datePlusEight: ' + datePlusEight);

      var newDateIs = new Date(datePlusEight);
      Logger.log('newDateIs: ' + newDateIs);
      Logger.log('newDateIs: ' + newDateIs.toString());

      sh.getRange(rowOfCellEdited, 4).setValue(newDateIs);
    };
  };
};
```

Comment out the `Logger.log()` statements for use.  To test, edit a cell in column C, with a date right next to it in the same row, but in column B.

In the spreadsheet, under the Tools menu, choose Script Editor, copy the code and paste it into the script editor.